# Lua's tostring() in C?

Tags: lua

Is there a Lua API function equivalent to tostring(), or do I have to do the following in my C code?

```
lua_getglobal(L, "tostring");
// ... push value to convert, and:
lua_call(L, 1, 1);
```

The long story:

I'm writing an `alert(message)` function in C (callable from Lua) that would show a message to the user. But if `message` isn't a string (e.g., a boolean or a nil), I want to convert it to something sane. There's a Lua function to do this, `tostring()`, but I was wondering if Lua's C API provides a "direct" way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`luaL_tolstring`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_tolstring)

From reference:

> [-0, +1, e]
>
> ```
> const char *luaL_tolstring (lua_State *L, int idx, size_t *len);
> ```
>
> Converts any Lua value at the given index to a C string in a reasonable format. The resulting string is pushed onto the stack and also returned by the function. If `len` is not `NULL`, the function also sets `*len` with the string length.
>
> If the value has a metatable with a "`__tostring`" field, then `luaL_tolstring` calls the corresponding metamethod with the value as argument, and uses the result of the call as its result.

Comment: Thanks. (Unfortunately, this functions doesn't exist in 5.1 (only in 5.2), but at least it shows me that there was a need to create such a function.)

Comment: @Niccolo M of course it exists in 5.1, it's lua_tolstring

Comment: @W.B. you're confusing `lua_tolstring` with `luaL_tolstring`.